# Ошибка1073741855 (0x4000001f) при попытке преобразования null к типу, try-catch не работает

Tags: c#

Есть код:

```
return ((IMenuItemVM) ((IContentVMBase) ChoosedMenu.Content).VM).CanContinue;
```

Все работает, но если, допустим свойство `Content` или `VM` или `CanContinue` равно `null`, то программа падает с ошибкой:

```
Программа "[8112] Blabla.exe" завершилась с кодом 1073741855 (0x4000001f).
```

Проблема в том, что даже если мы вставим подобное:

```
try {
    return ((IMenuItemVM) ((IContentVMBase) ChoosedMenu.Content).VM).CanContinue;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
return false;
```

То ничего не изменится. Всё равно оно будет падать `с кодом 1073741855 (0x4000001f).`

Так-же у меня включены все исключения.

[image: Параметры исключений]

Comment: [Program and debugger quit without indication of problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4532457/312041)

Comment: @tym32167 я так понимаю, что `You should enable debugging unmanaged code` это `Включить отладку в машинном коде`? Если да, то при включении ее и попытке запуска программы у меня `programname.exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова.`

Comment: `programname.exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова` ну дак уберите точку останова

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня в программе вообще нигде нет точек останова... Причем это не может быть тем, что я просто её не замечаю - я их всех убрал через `Отладка -> Удалить все точки останова`

Comment: `Так-же у меня включены все исключения.` попробуйте выключить. Эта ошибка скорее из неуправляемого кода лезет

Comment: Таак, потыкав разные галочки я понял, что `debugging unmanaged code` переехало в `Проект` -> `Сборка` -> `Разрешить небезопасный код`. После включения этой галочки программу не выкидывает, а дебаггер просто останавливается на ошибке. Теперь вопрос скорее в том, почему игнорируется try-catch?

Comment: Так, тут мой видимо косяк, с не понимаем работы прерывания на исключениях, ибо действительно - `Так-же у меня включены все исключения - попробуйте выключить.`, если включить все, то дебаггер будет останавливаться на них вне зависимости от того, обработаны они или нет. После отключения обработанные работают нормально, на не обработанных дебаггер останавливается. Спасибо.

Comment: Хотел, пользуясь случаем, спросить. А разве в C# при возникновении исключения в `try/catch` конструкции происходит дальнейшее выполнение кода расположенного после неё? Судя из моего скромного опыта в Java нет. Поэтому `return false;` строка должна находиться в секции `catch`. В этом случае возможно и не будет вываливаться программа с ошибкой, т.к. функция вернёт в любом случае значение. Поправьте, если неправ.

Comment: @Rootware `Поэтому return false; строка должна находиться в секции catch` ... `т.к. функция вернёт в любом случае значение` - а если исключения не будет и код в catch не будет вызван, что вернетнся? Вы наверное `catch` с `finally` путаете.

Comment: @tym32167 в моей скромной практике не было случаев когда исключение не выбрасывалось в секции `try/catch` при ошибке. Возможно они есть, но я не видел/читал об этом. Но мой финт очень помогает, когда есть предположения о возникновении NPE там, где нужно обязательно вернуть `bool` или `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дополнение к совершенно справедливому комментарию tym32167 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532457/program-and-debugger-quit-without-indication-of-problem, ИМХО, если вместо Вашей конструкции

```
return ((IMenuItemVM) ((IContentVMBase) ChoosedMenu.Content).VM).CanContinue;
```

использовать более старомодную и менее лаконичную конструкцию:

```
IContentVMBase content = ChoosedMenu.Content as IContentVMBase;
if( content == null ) return false;

IMenuItemVM mnuItem = content.VM as IMenuItemVM;
if( mnuItem == null ) return false;

return mnuItem.CanContinue;
```

то джентльмены находят, что она способствует сохранению нервных клеток.

UpDate: дополнение к ответу по просьбе автора вопроса и сформулированное автором вопроса SKProCH о способе настроек дебаггера, когда используется смесь из небезопасного кода:

"Что-бы программа перестала падать, а дебаггер начал останавливаться на ошибке нужно включить **Проект** -> **Сборка** -> **Разрешить небезопасный код**. Что бы перестать try-catch необходимо **выключить прерывание работы на нужном вам типе Exception** "

Comment: Можете дополнить ответ информацией из комментариев под вопросом?

Comment: Я добавил ссылку, на которую указал tym32167.

Comment: Да мне кажется, что следующую информацию тоже нужно добавить: `Что-бы программа перестала падать, а дебаггер начал останавливаться на ошибке нужно включить **Проект** -> **Сборка** -> **Разрешить небезопасный код**. Что бы перестать try-catch необходимо **выключить прерывание работы на нужном вам типе Excetion**`